# Scala Play2.4 / Sbt multi-project build not working

Tags: scala, build, sbt, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to fragment my sbt scala Play project into several buildable modules. I read [the official sbt multi-project guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html), [Play 2.4.x multi-project guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTSubProjects), and these examples: [playing-microservices](https://github.com/knoldus/playing-microservices) and [the example from the Scala Cookbook](https://github.com/alvinj/SbtSubProjectsExample), [Another good example](https://github.com/kifi/multiproject). They all subtly diverge and I've had no luck so far.

I keep getting the following:

```
$ sbt (or ./activator)

> project myPlay
> compile
... OK 
> start
...
(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

Error: Could not find or load main class play.core.server.ProdServerStart
```

How do I get past this?

Here's what I did:

My first step was to create two toplevel dirs: `my-common-lib` and `my-play-proj`. I moved `/app /conf /public /test` into `/my-play-project`, and created a `/src/main/scala/fooPackage/..` dir in `my-common-lib`, s.t.:

```
/my-common-lib
- /src
/my-play-project
- /app
- /conf
  - /application.conf
  - /routes
  - /evolutions
  ...
- /test
- /public
/build.sbt
/project
- /build.properties
- /plugins.sbt
```

Then I changed my `build.sbt` as follows:

```
import sbt.Keys._

lazy val root = (project in file (".")) settings (
    name := "root-overlord",
    version := "1.0.0"
  ) aggregate (common, myPlay)

lazy val common = (project in file ("my-common-lib")) settings (commonSettings: _*) settings (
    name := "some-common-lib",
    version := "1.0.0"
  )

lazy val myPlay = (project in file ("my-play-project")).
  enablePlugins(PlayScala).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings (
    name := """my-play""",
    version := "1.8.2",
    // Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
    // other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
    routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator,
    javaOptions in run += "-javaagent:" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.8.jar -Xmx2G",
    fork in run := true,
    connectInput in run := true,
    javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=test.application.conf",
    parallelExecution in Test := false,
    packageName in Universal := "myPlayProj"
  ).
  dependsOn(common % "compile->compile;test->test")


lazy val commonSettings = Seq (
  organization := "the-great-empire",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
  libraryDependencies := Seq(
       ...
  ),
  resolvers := Seq(
    ...
  ),
  javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=test.application.conf",
  parallelExecution in Test := false
)
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: It seems that specifing `libraryDependencies := Seq(...)` instead of `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...)` in commonSettings has wiped out the Play libraries which should have been loaded to the myPlay project by the sbt-play plugin.

Comment: Does the output of `sbt "inspect libraryDependencies"` correctly contain the Play core libraries (`scala.collection.Seq[sbt.ModuleID] = List(..., com.typesafe.play:play-server:2.5.3, com.typesafe.play:play-netty-server:2.5.3, ...)`)?

Comment: You solved it! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to be of your help!